# understanding the node.js event queue and process.nextTick

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback, eventqueue

I'm having trouble understanding exactly how `process.nextTick` does its thing. I thought I understood, but I can't seem to replicate how I feel this should work:

```
var handler = function(req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-type' : 'text/html'});
    foo(function() {
        console.log("bar");
    });
    console.log("received");
    res.end("Hello, world!");
}

function foo(callback) {
    var i = 0;
    while(i<1000000000) i++;
    process.nextTick(callback);
}

require('http').createServer(handler).listen(3000);
```

While `foo` is looping, I'll send over several requests, assuming that `handler` will be queued several times behind `foo` with `callback` being enqueued only when `foo` is finished.

If I'm correct about how this works, I assume the outcome will look like this:

```
received
received
received
received
bar
bar
bar
bar
```

But it doesn't, it's just sequential:

```
received
bar
received
bar
received
bar
received
bar
```

I see that `foo` is returning before executing `callback` which is expected, but it seems that `callback` is NEXT in line, rather than at the end of the queue, behind all of the requests coming in. Is that the way it works? Maybe I'm just not understanding how exactly the event queue in node works. And please don't point me [here](http://howtonode.org/understanding-process-next-tick). Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

process.nextTick put the callback on the next tick that is going to be executed, not at the end of the tick queue.

Node.js doc (http://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_nexttick_callback) say:
"It typically runs before any other I/O events fire, but there are some exceptions."

setTimeout(callback, 0) will probably work more like you describe.

Comment: No, `setTimeout` behaved the same way. I guess I'm really asking how I'm supposed to start processing http requests before a previous request is finished.

Comment: Actually, I realized that `setTimeout` does exactly what I was looking for, so I apologize. But what exactly is `process.nextTick` for if it doesn't allow for the interleaving of cpu intensive tasks and http processing?

Comment: "not at the end of the tick" — so, is there a way to push an arbitrary function at the end of the event queue? Is `setTimeout(fn, 0)` a recommended way or just a workaround?

Answer (score 1):

You should certainly read the link fgascon provided, and perhaps

https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/3335
for more background.

Use process.nextTick for when you want to call some code before any IO, but after the calling context has returned (usually because you want to register listeners on an event emitter and need to return the created emitter before you can register anything).