# The best way to do a Callback after For in NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, for-loop, asynchronous, callback

I have been developing in PHP for many years and now I´m trying to learn NodeJS, and I´m having problems with asynchronous functions...

I have this function in NodeJS (*source is an array of users*):

```
//userformat.js

var age = module.exports.age = function(date){

  var diff = new Date - new Date(date);
  var diffdays = diff / 1000 / (60 * 60 * 24);
  var age = Math.floor(diffdays / 365.25);

  return age;

}

...etc.

//index.js

function format(source, me, callback){

    var len = source.length

    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++){

        source[i]['_age'] = userFormat.age(source[i]['birthday']);
        source[i]['_rating'] = userFormat.rating(source[i]['votes']);
        source[i]['_is_followed'] = userFormat.followed(source[i]['fllws'], me);

    }

    callback(null, source);

}
```

I know that function is **wrong** in Node, because is possible that the function calls the callback before the functions in the for() had finished, and the values in the array could be undefined, for this reason I changed the function using callbacks:

```
//userformat.js

var age = module.exports.age = function(date, callback){

      var diff = new Date - new Date(date);
      var diffdays = diff / 1000 / (60 * 60 * 24);
      var age = Math.floor(diffdays / 365.25);

      callback(age);

    }
...etc.

//index.js

function format(source, me, callback){

    var len = source.length

    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++){

        userFormat.age(source[i]['birthday'], function(resul){

            source[i]['_age'] = resul;

            userFormat.rating(source[i]['votes'], function(resul){

                source[i]['_rating'] = resul;

                userFormat.followed(source[i]['fllws'], me, function(resul){

                    source[i]['_is_followed'] = resul;

                    //Callback
                    if (i == len-1){
                        callback(null, source);
                    }

                })

            })


        })

    }

}
```

That is correct? I have another way to do it more efficient or elegant?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you misunderstood the concept of asynchronous in nodeJS. Your code isn't asynchronous and your callback will always be called after the loop.

Check this question : [how do i create a non-blocking asynchronous function in node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2878008/how-do-i-create-a-non-blocking-asynchronous-function-in-node-js)

Comment: Yes.. I know that the callback is called after the loop, but the vars inside the loop are setting asynchronously. userFormat.age(), userFormat.rating() and userFormat.followed() are functions that returns a value.

Comment: Could you show what the userFormat methods are doing exactly ?

Comment: I have edit my first question... I´m sorry, asynchronous methods are very confused for me...

Comment: Your methods are not asynchronous (at least the age method). Read the explanations from the link I gave you, it should help you understand it. If you really need your methods to be run asynchronously I think you should use the process object (http://nodejs.org/api/process.html), and the nextTick method.

Comment: Thank you Arthur, I have to study more :) . I´ll read the links, are very interesting