# Node.js Asynchrounous requests

Tags: node.js, express

I have an application which shows real-time prices of different markets to users. I tried ajax and WebSockets both node.js takes all requests synchronously which delays the data showing on the user dashboard. So how to make an application like that in Node.js which sends data at the same time to all the users.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how do i create a non-blocking asynchronous function in node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2878008/how-do-i-create-a-non-blocking-asynchronous-function-in-node-js)

Comment: It would be useful to see a sample of your code in order to determine which direction you've taken and how we can steer you towards a solution